# Input type number doesn't change value on scroll

Tags: html, reactjs, input

I've got simple `<input type="number" />` in my React project and it don't change value on scroll.

But if you write something like  `<input type="number" onWheel={() => {}}/>`, it will change value with page scrolling.
The same happening on every page except one.

On MDN there is the same trouble: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/number

First input is scrollable, the second one is not.
In Firefox everything is OK. This happens in Chrome v77 and Safari on High Sierra (Edge doesn't implement this feature as far as I know).

Comment: Sounds like a WebKit bug. What is it you are asking?

Comment: I want this input to behave like in Firefox. So to change value on scroll

Comment: Based on what you write, I tested `<input type="number" onwheel="">` and with that code mouse wheel scrolling to change the value is working on chrome v79. I have been unable to figure out why scrolling works on the first MDN example and not the others.

Comment: Yep, it's working but there is side effect of scrolling page that doesn't seem ok for me